# Java: ActionListener и наследование полей

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!
У меня такое задание: нужно написать программу в среде Eclipse таким образом, чтобы вся обработка событий (нажатие клавиши, кнопки на форме) находилась в одном классе, а вся работа с интерфейсом - в другом. Чтобы объяснить проблему, написал простенькую программу Теst: вот она.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Ecouter extends Fenetre implements ActionListener {    
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        
    Fenetre.monButton1.setName("name");     
}
}
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Fenetre {
    public JButton monButton1;
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Fenetre InterfaceGraphique = new Fenetre();
        InterfaceGraphique.dessine();   
    }
    public void dessine()
    {
        JFrame fenetre = new JFrame ("Exemple d'interface");
        JButton monButton1 = new JButton("Bouton1");
        monButton1.addActionListener(new Ecouter());
        fenetre.getContentPane().add(monButton1);
        fenetre.pack();
        fenetre.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Смысл программы в том, что при нажатии кнопки на форме, название кнопки должно поменятся, но вместо этого программа зависает. Возможная проблема в том, что я не правильно использую механизмы наследования: extends Fenetre, но без этого я не знаю, как получить доступ из одного класса к полям другого класса, так, чтобы можно было бы их изменять.
Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: мсье! вы подлый лжец:

> написал простенькую программу Теst

очень сомневаюсь в том чтоб русский человек, при изучении программирования, давал французские названия переменным и классам

Comment: Я во Франции практику прохожу >;->

Comment: добрый совет: если знаете что Ваш код будут\могут смотреть люди не знающие французского - давайте названия на английском. Иногда совершенно не доставляет читать код на неизвестном языке, особенно с комментариями на нём же >.<

Comment: мой косяк, вначала разместил, потом посмотрел

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка состоит в том, что вы передаете в обработчик новый экземпляр класса, в родителе которого не инициализирован `monButton1`, надо сделать примерно так (без танцев с родителем):

```
import java.awt.event.*; 
public class Ecouter implements ActionListener {     
private JButton monButton;
public Ecouter(JButton monButton) {
   this.monButton=monButton;
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {         
    monButton.setName("name");      
} 
} 
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
public class Fenetre { 
    public JButton monButton1; 
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    { 
        Fenetre InterfaceGraphique = new Fenetre(); 
        InterfaceGraphique.dessine();    
    } 
    public void dessine() 
    { 
        JFrame fenetre = new JFrame ("Exemple d'interface"); 
        JButton monButton1 = new JButton("Bouton1"); 
        monButton1.addActionListener(new Ecouter(monButton1)); 
        fenetre.getContentPane().add(monButton1); 
        fenetre.pack(); 
        fenetre.setVisible(true); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: 1 пост = 1 вопрос - соблюдайте правила. Выставляйте вопрос